# How to obtain 100% success geocoding in Android

Tags: android, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

What are the methods I can use to find latitude and longitude of an address without any problems?
The methods I know are:
- **Geocoder** (but sometimes there's the "**Service not available**" problem for Android 4.0 and Android 4.1)
- **Google Geocoding API** (but this solution doesn't work with mobile connection of some mobile operators: the request always returns **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT**. Those mobile operators use NAT overloading, assigning the same IP to many devices).
Any other methods or ideas for resolving these geocoding issues?

Answer (score 0):

For solving the "Service not available" **Geocoder problem** you need to **set the Project Build Target to API 16**.
In Eclipse: Right Click Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Android -> Project Build Target.

Comment: @aat seemed it worked the first time I tried on real device, but in the end it doesn't work... Have you got the same problem?

Comment: Yeah I have the same problem and I'm looking for a right answer. The only one seems to be using Google geocoding API but it is limited ...

Comment: @aat yes but there are some problems with Geocoding API too: some mobile operators have NAT overloading that makes a lot of requests answered with "OVER QUERY LIMIT"... I don't know how to get a 100% success Geocoding... If you find a solution please let me know